# Docker port expose

Tags: docker, boot2docker

As a follow up to [Linking Docker Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891782/linking-docker-containers/28900139)

I've linked both a mongo, redis container with my nodejs app container successfully. My node app is now running inside my container but for some reason I can't access it:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
3f8790bb7cc5        mseay/myapp:latest        "/bin/bash"            2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   myapp
5470cdd876eb        redis:latest              "/entrypoint.sh redi   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    6379/tcp                 redis
36c61197d8bd        mongo:latest              "/entrypoint.sh mong   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    27017/tcp                mongo
```

Inside my container, my node app is running on port 3000. My docker run command specifies to map 3000 in my container to 3000 on my host:

```
docker run -i -t -p 3000:3000 --name myapp --link mongo:MONGODB --link redis:REDIS mseay/myapp /bin/bash
```

docker port shows

```
3000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3000
```

But, when I goto localhost:3000 or try to curl it:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

Apologies for being noobish. Any help is always greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `boot2docker`.  The ports are published *on the virtual machine running docker*.  You can get the ip address of that vm by running `boot2docker ip`.

So, for your service on port 3000, you could run:

```
curl http://$(boot2docker ip):3000/
```